# How can I move data from views.py to a models.py in python/django in this case?

Tags: python, django

I put these files in the order the data travels. First the user submits a ticker via Charfield on the add file. Then the add function creates an instance of the score class by submitting the ticker value, which works. I also calculate points in add, but I can't figure out a way to send points to the class in models also.

All of the examples I've seen on StackOverflow usually have variables in the class being related to some CharField or ForeignKey. So it possible to send points to score()?

I also know scoreCalculate works.

The error this code generates:

```
File "~/models.py", line 6, in score
    points;     

NameError: name 'points' is not defined
```

Of course it isn't defined, I'm just not sure what to define it as.

add.html

```
<form action="{% url 'add' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

    <label for="ticker">Ticker</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="ticker" id="ticker"/>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import score
from Rssfeed import scoreCalculate

def add(request):
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        ticker = request.POST['ticker']

        pts = scoreCalculate(ticker=ticker)
        sc = score(ticker = ticker)

        sc.save()

        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'add.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class score(models.Model):

    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    points; #not sure what to put here
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. If you want to save `points` on the model, it needs to be a field. If not, why do you want to "send" it to the model? What exactly are you doing with those points?

Comment: I want to be able to store them so I can print the 10 most recently searched tickers and their points on a page. I am getting pretty much all of my information from a tutorial so my set of tools is limited. Is there an easier way to store and retrieve the tickers along with their respective points?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the points into the score object when you create it.

In views.py, use the following line when you create the `score` object:

```
sc = score(ticker=ticker, points=pts)
```

And in models.py, use the following field in your score model:

```
class score(models.Model):

    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    points = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Comment: The new error that goes along with it now is OperationalError at /add (1054, "Unknown column 'points' in 'field list'"). Sounds like a mysql error now.

Comment: Did you remember to ```python manage.py makemigrations; python manage.py migrate```?

Comment: Yes, django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'senty_score.points' in 'field list'") i tried it again just in case and ended up with close to the same error when i ran the site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to find a way to store the points in a score board. If that's true, then you should just add the score as an integer/decimal field and let the model handle storage for you.

Something like this:

class score(models.Model):

```
ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
points = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Or for integer:

`class score(models.Model):`

```
ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
points = models.IntegerField()
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Comment: That worked after the migration. Now I just have some kind of Mysql error: Unknown column 'points' in 'field list'" This was a python question but do you know how to resolve that?

Comment: I've found that sometimes the SQL migrations fail due to SQL server issues. Look at the migration file and try to run the SQL manually. If it gives you an error you might have to manually add the column to the table using your SQL interface.